# UI Toolkit not firing button clicked event

Tags: unity, c#, events, unity-ui

I'm using the new UI Toolkit and new Input System together, and I've setup everything correctly the Input Actions has separate input for UI, the Input System UI Input Module is setup correctly, the Visual Tree works in the scene, and my custom script has no errors, but for some reason my Button doesn't fire the clicked event. Everything works when debugged, I also made the button change color when active, which it does, but it doesn't fire an event... 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remember to always share code as text, not as an image.

Comment: @DMGregory right, will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't mentioned how my UI Controller works, turns out that disabling a UI Document removes all events. Just reassign the events in the OnEnable() method.